# How do I call a generic method with a Type property?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following situation:

```
public class ListingAttribute : AgencyServicesApi.Attribute
{
    public Type ClrType { get; set; }
    //public void SetValue(object value)
    //{
    //    this.SetValueGen<ClrType>((ClrType)value);
    //}

    public void SetValueGen<TValue>(TValue value)
    {
        var t = typeof(TValue);
        Value = // Use conversion methods based on ClrType here.
    }
}
```

I can't make `ListingAttribute` generic and use a generic parameter `T` for `ClrType` because I have to set the type at runtime. `AgencyServicesApi.Attribute` has a smelly `Value` property of type `string`, regardless of what whether the content of `Value` should be any other type. I am trying to extend `AgencyServicesApi.Attribute`, and based on a configuration file, set the `ClrType` correctly, and be able to add proper validation and `ToString` implementation.

How can I call generic method `SetValueGen` and pass it the type of `ClrType` as a type parameter? `SetValue` is commented out because it doesn't compile, and I wouldn't expect it to, but I am stuck on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code almost as-is:

```
public class ListingAttribute : AgencyServicesApi.Attribute
{
    public Type ClrType { get; set; }

    public void SetValue(object value)
    {
        SetValueGen((dynamic)value);
    }

    public void SetValueGen<TValue>(TValue value)
    {
        var t = typeof(TValue);
        Value = // Use conversion methods based on ClrType here.
    }
}
```

But this seems wrong... Why don't you simply do:

```
public void SetValue(object value)
{
    var t = value.GetType();
    Value = // Use conversion methods based on t here.
}
```

Comment: I want to make decisions based on the `ClrType` of the object, not the type of the value passed to `SetValue`, as your 2nd example does. I want to only accept types that match ClrType, but maybe I must just use old fashioned type validation checks.

Comment: I see... I guess reflection is your best bet:  `if (ClrType.IsInstanceOfType(value))`, but it's still unclear to me what exactly you're trying to do here so I can't edit my answer in a meaningful way unless you provide more detail